# Why a structure is allowed to have "pointer to its own type" as member but not "(an array of the) structure type" itself?

Tags: c, struct, declaration, definition

when i try to declare the following function

```
typedef struct TRIE_NODE
{
    char* word;
    struct TRIE_NODE node[26];
}TRIE_NODE;
```

I get the following error:

> definition of 'struct TRIE_NODE' is not complete until the closing '}'

However, if i declare this function with a pointer to the 26 nodes, it compiles just fine.

```
typedef struct TRIE_NODE
{
    char* word;
    struct TRIE_NODE* node[26];
}TRIE_NODE;
```

I imagine that, since this is not an instance, it's impossible for me to get a pointer to the first of those 26 arrays, but if that is the problem, how is     `TRIE_NODE* node[26]` not also a problem? Isn't this declaration equivalent to `TRIE_NODE node[1][26]`?

Comment: You're declaring a struct inside the struct of the struct you're trying to define... say that 10x fast ;)

Comment: Even if it did work, wouldn't it be infinite size. Since every TRIE_NODE contains 26 TRIE_NODES, which each contain 26 TRIE_NODEs and so on ...

Comment: because  Recursive definition is compiler can not determine the size.

Comment: "Isn't this declaration equivalent to `TRIE_NODE node[1][26]`?" - No, it isn't. Why?

Comment: "when i try to declare the following function" - Which function? There is no function! And an array is not a pointer is not an array!

Comment: `struct Box { struct Box x };` ...

Comment: Why the down vote? Feel like this was a good question and it has a good answer

Comment: What makes you think arrays would somehow be possible when single objects of the struct type itself are not? **Arrays are not pointers!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *when i try to declare the following function*

***Wait!!*** that's not a function, that's `typedef`-ing a structure, a user-defined type.

---

That said, in the first case,

```
typedef struct TRIE_NODE
{
    char* word;
    struct TRIE_NODE node[26];  //array of type struct TRIE_NODE
}TRIE_NODE;
```

if this has to be possible, compiler needs to know the size of the `struct TRIE_NODE` ***before*** it has been defined, which is impossible. So it is invalid.

On th other hand,

```
typedef struct TRIE_NODE
{
    char* word;
    struct TRIE_NODE* node[26];  //array of pointers (of type struct TRIE_NODE)
}TRIE_NODE;
```

is fine, as you're allocating (array of) pointers to the structure, the actual size of the structure is not required to be known by compiler at that point. So, the compiler happily allocates the pointers and the definition (construct) is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i see the problem with the first declaration now. However, aren't pointers and arrays almost interchangeable? `struct TRIE_NODE* node[26]` shouldn't be equivalent to `struct TRIE_NODE[1][26]`? I just tried it and i get the same error as the first declaration. I say that because i was reading "C primer plus" and he oftenly mentions that both are interchangeable to the compiler, it all becomes the same pointer declaration at compilation time.

Comment: @Selhar nopes, they are not same neither interchangable, in general. Google "Arrays are not pointers", read the C faq.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, that's a bit depressing, i just spent a huge amount of time reading "C primer plus" and if he's wrong about that, i wonder what else i learned wrong.

Comment: @Selhar: **Never ever** think of arrays being pointers being arrays! But your conclusion about the "C primer plus" is good. Sadly to say, but there is a lot of nonsense being written about C. It becomes worse, as it actually is not **that** complicated. But one has to understand Cs fundamental concepts.

Comment: @Olaf What authors would you recommend for CS books in general? I plan on learning C++ after C, my idea was to read "C++ Primer plus", since i liked "C primer plus" so much.

Comment: @Selhar: Whoever wrote the C standard document, search for C11 n1570 or look at the info-page. Not good to learn, but the only authoritative resource. Seriously: I don't know any good C book (and asking is off-topic here). Yet there is a recommendation site for C and C++ books on stack-overflow (also keep in mind they are **different** languages even for identical syntax!).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your own question, ask: how many bytes will

```
struct TRIE_NODE node[26];
```

occupy?  In fact, what would you expect `sizeof(struct TRIE_NODE)` to be?

The reason

```
struct TRIE_NODE *node[26];
```

works is that we know the value of `sizeof(struct TRIE_NODE*)`.  Because *all struct pointers have the same size*, we can allocate an array of *N* struct pointers, no matter their type, even if incompletely defined.

> aren't pointers and arrays almost interchangeable?

The *syntax* for pointers and arrays is similar.  You can subscript a pointer, and you can add to an array's address.  But they *define* different things.  Basically: an array holds data, and a pointer holds an address.

In certain parts of the C standard library, you'll find structures defined like this:

```
struct S {
    int len;
    char data[1];
};
```

You might be tempted to ask why not use a pointer?

```
struct Z {
    int len;
    char *data;
};
```

Answer: `struct S` is actually bigger than the 5 or so bytes it seems to occupy, and the data portion begins immediately after `len`.  In the putative `struct Z` example, `data` doesn't *begin* the data; the data would be somewhere else, wherever `data` *points*.

Assuming the structures are appropriate initialized, in both cases `data[0]` will address the first byte of the array.  They're syntactically similar.  But the memory layout is different.  In the `S` case, that byte will be pretty close to `(char*)&len + sizeof(len)`.  In the `Z` case it will be wherever `data` points.

Comment: Pointers might have different sizes. (But all pointers to struct type have the same size, for this reason).

Comment: I stand corrected, thank you.  That must be what *Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.* means.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody mention this, but if struct was allowed to have member or array of itself (not a pointer, but regular member or array), then the struct would be recursive and with infinite size, because the member will have one more member inside of same type and so on until infinity.